# PubKey Authentication not Working

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, mac

I tried setting up PubKey authentication between my Mac and CentOS dedi server, but something is up...

Here's the steps I took:

```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then

```
  chmod 700 .ssh/ && chmod 600 .ssh/*
```

Then

```
  scp id_rsa.pub root@dedi:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then (sorry about all these "Then"'s)

```
  ssh root@dedi
```

And what do you know? I get prompted for my password.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's the output of `ssh -v root@dedi`:

```
  SH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for dedi
  debug1: Connecting to dediserversdomain.com.au.co.net.org.bz [198.100.145.168] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /Users/someone/.ssh/id_rsa,~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/someone/.ssh/id_rsa,~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
  debug1: Server host key: RSA (my rsa key)
  debug1: Host 'dediserversdomain.com.au.co.net.org.bz' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /Users/someone/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: /Users/someone/.ssh/id_rsa,~/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Next authentication method: password
  root@dediserversdomain.com.au.co.net.org.bz's password:
```

**EDIT**: Output of `stat .ssh` and `stat .ssh/*` from within my dedi:

```
  File: `.ssh'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
  Device: 801h/2049d    Inode: 1175048     Links: 2
  Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
  Access: 2014-09-21 11:21:43.000000000 -0400
  Modify: 2014-09-21 10:52:26.000000000 -0400
  Change: 2014-09-21 11:21:49.000000000 -0400

  File: `.ssh/authorized_keys'
  Size: 411         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: 801h/2049d    Inode: 1175045     Links: 1
  Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
  Access: 2014-09-21 10:52:26.000000000 -0400
  Modify: 2014-09-21 10:52:26.000000000 -0400
  Change: 2014-09-21 11:21:43.000000000 -0400
```

*EDIT*: Here's the output of `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`

```
  debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
  debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
  debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
  debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
  debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
  debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
  debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
  Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
  Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
  Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
  Cannot bind any address.
```

*EDIT*: Here's the output of `grep 'sshd' /var/log/*`:
      Binary file /var/log/btmp matches
      Binary file /var/log/btmp-20140901 matches
      /var/log/dovecot-info.log:Aug 08 09:10:03 pop3-login: Info: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=, method=PLAIN, rip=211.43.207.112, lip=198.100.145.168
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0-0-0-0_PORT-22_procname|sshd
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0-0-0-0_PORT-22_cmdline|/usr/sbin/sshd 
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0-0-0-0_PORT-22_exe|/usr/sbin/sshd
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0_PORT-22_procname|sshd
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0_PORT-22_cmdline|/usr/sbin/sshd 
      /var/log/install_rtm.log:rtm hINFO_TCP_LISTEN_IP-0_PORT-22_exe|/usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: Did you also set up/confirm that the remote permissions on the `/root/.ssh` directory (0700) and `/root/.ssh/authorzed_keys` file (0600) are correct? (And generally remote root login should be disabled; you should log in first using an unprivileged account and than use `sudo`)

Comment: That's correct. I will add the output of `stat .ssh` and `stat .ssh/*` in my OP (executed from my dedi).

Comment: @HBruijn please see my OP.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton No SSH logs there (/var/log/secure) — any ideas?

Comment: @user3650841 Set `LogLevel DEBUG` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @XavierLucas — I did that, then typed `service sshd restart`; logged out; re-authenticated, and `/var/log/secure` still has no contents.

Comment: @user3650841 Is rsyslog running? Restart it and check configured facilities.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, set `LogLevel` to `DEBUG3`, then `service sshd restart`

`tail -F /var/log/secure > /root/tmp.txt`: this is a useful way of getting only the logs relating to the test; although you'll get a few old lines beforehand. It will appear to hang (you can put it in the background if you like)

Attempt to auth again (presumably it will fail). Kill the `tail -F ...` job you started earlier. The reason for the failure will very likely be seen in `/root/tmp.txt`.

Most of the time its due to a poorly formatted (or line-wrapped) entry in your `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`  (mind the American English spelling).

Other common reasons:

- `AllowRoot` is set to no;
- `PubKeyAuthentication` is set to no (mind also `RSAAuthentication`, which is for SSH version 1 (which should be disabled)

You might also be on the lookout for a `Limit` stanza which might treat you differently.

Comment: None of this worked. Even when I changed `LogLevel` to `DEBUG3` — and restarted sshd, as soon as I login to my server again, /var/log/secure is completely empty. Would you like me to post anything in particular on my OP? Any outputs?

Comment: You might like to grep through /var/log/ looking for 'sshd'. It might end up in 'messages' or somewhere else according to you logging configuration.

Comment: —— I'm adding the output of `grep 'sshd' /var/log/*` to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Is selinux on? Check /var/log/messages to check it out. If selinux is not the problem. Try stop sshd service and start it on console:

```
user@server# /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

This doesn't help as you got already in use the port with the main daemon.

```
  Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
  Cannot bind any address.
```

SSHD pub key auth may fail for:

1. Invalid permissions on server user's home ~/.ssh with perms other than 700 (try checking out if the perms are the same of the one you put on the src)
2. ~/.ssh/authorized_keys with perms other than 600 (try checking out if the perms are the same of the one you put on the src)
3. Different owner of ~/.ssh or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (if you used scp with your user I don't think this may be a problem)
4. SElinux missconfiuration
5. Wrong set of keys

You may check out

```
#tail -f /var/log/secure
```

When you are trying to connect

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: did you get the execution of /usr/sbin/sshd -d ?

Comment: Now that I've followed more info up there ^^ I have some output from that. I'll add it to my OP.

Comment: yeh, you should __stop__ first your sshd service before executing /usr/sbin/sshd -d . Don't worry it would not log you out.

Comment: — when I stop my SSHD service (I've done it in the past) — it logs me straight out. Makes sense though, since it stops listening on port 22.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense as far as sshd spawns a child proccess that handles the connection on other port than the 22, but well whatever bind the new sshd to Port 2222 and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if selinux is running with

```
sestatus
```

Turn it off (temporarily) with

```
setenforce 0
```

If you are then allowed to login, you have two options: 
You can turn it off permanently by editing:

```
/etc/sysconfg/selinux
```

I cant remember exactly what this file looks like, but IIRC its very simple.

OR, you can ensure the selinux context is set correctly on the .ssh folder and files

restorecon -R ~/.ssh

Comment: This is not the problem.